# Business logic in service method

Tags: java, object-oriented

I'm currently writing a small asset tracking system.

The implementation should meet the following requirements:

> **The system**; scans the transfers every 15 minutes. If the transfer is
>   accepted by the receiver by the specified transfer time, realizes the
>   transfer. When a transfer is realized, assets are assigned to the
>   receiver as of transfer time; if the transfer is permanent, actual
>   owner is changed also.
>
> **The system**; If the transfer operation is not accepted by the receiver
>   by the specified transfer time; cancels the transfer.

Above requirement is dependent on this straight-forward requirement (UI related parts omitted):

> **Transferring user**; When a new transfer is started, 
>   [...]
>   and specifies
>
> - the time when the transfer will be realized
> - whether the transfer is temporary or permanent
> - assets to be transferred
> - the receiver
> - [... and saves ....]

The implementation:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
@Service
public class TransferServiceImpl implements TransferService {

    private Repository<Transfer, Long> repository;
    private Repository<Asset, Long> assetRepository;

    @Override
    public void informTransferTimeIsUp(long transferId) {
        Transfer transfer = repository.get(transferId);
        transfer.informTransferTimeIsUp();

        if (transfer.isRealized()) {
            Set<Asset> transferredAssets = assetRepository.getAll(transfer.getTransferredAssets());
            for (Asset asset : transferredAssets) {
                if (TransferType.TEMPORARY.equals(transfer.getTransferType())) {
                    asset.transferTemporarily(transfer.getReceiver());
                } else {
                    asset.transferPermanently(transfer.getReceiver());
                }
                assetRepository.update(asset);
            }
        }

        repository.update(transfer);
    }

}

class Transfer {
    long receiver;
    Date transferTime;
    TransferType transferType;
    Set<Long> transferredAssets = new HashSet<Long>();

    boolean accepted;
    boolean timeIsUp;
    boolean realized;
    boolean cancelled;


    public void informTransferTimeIsUp() {
        this.timeIsUp = true;

        if (accepted) {
            this.realized = true;
        } else {
            this.cancelled = true;
        }
    }

    public long getReceiver() {
        return this.receiver;
    }

    public Set<Long> getTransferredAssets() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(transferredAssets);
    }

    public TransferType getTransferType() {
        return transferType;
    }

    public boolean isRealized() {
        return realized;
    }

}

class Asset {
    Long actualOwnerId;
    Long currentOwnerId;

    boolean blocked;

    public void transferTemporarily(long receiverId) {
        this.currentOwnerId = receiverId;
        this.unblockIfBlocked();
    }

    public void transferPermanently(long receiverId) {
        this.actualOwnerId = receiverId;
        this.currentOwnerId = receiverId;
        this.unblockIfBlocked();
    }

    private void unblockIfBlocked() {
        this.blocked = false;
    }

}
```

Dependencies to get the above code to compile:

```
interface TransferService {
    void informTransferTimeIsUp(long transferId);
}


interface Repository<TEntity, TKey> {

    TEntity get(TKey key);

    Set<TEntity> getAll(Set<TKey> keys);

    void update(TEntity asset);

}

enum TransferType {TEMPORARY, PERMANENT}
```

Is there too much business logic in the service layer?

Answer (score 2):

```
Set<Asset> transferredAssets = assetRepository.getAll(transfer.getTransferredAssets());
for (Asset asset : transferredAssets) { ... }
```

Since the transfer isn't done yet, and also to prevent ambiguity *post*-transfer, may I suggest renaming the method to `getAssets()`? You can also inline the call:

```
for (Asset asset : assetRepository.getAll(transfer.getTransferredAssets())) { ... }
```

Two minor improvements I can suggest for the snippet below:

1. It's safe to compare `enum`s by `==`.
2. Have a `transfer(TransferType, long)` method in `Asset` so that the toggling is done within `Asset`: callers only need to supply the `TransferType` value.

```
if (TransferType.TEMPORARY.equals(transfer.getTransferType())) {
    asset.transferTemporarily(transfer.getReceiver());
} else {
    asset.transferPermanently(transfer.getReceiver());
}
```

Since the use of `realized` and `cancelled` are just opposites of each other, you may want to consider having just a single `boolean` field, to keep the implementation simpler.

```
if (accepted) {
    this.realized = true;
} else {
    this.cancelled = true;
}
```

In `Asset`:

```
public void transferTemporarily(long receiverId) {
    this.currentOwnerId = receiverId;
    this.unblockIfBlocked();
}

public void transferPermanently(long receiverId) {
    this.actualOwnerId = receiverId;
    this.currentOwnerId = receiverId;
    this.unblockIfBlocked();
}
```

This can be slightly simplified as:

```
public void transferTemporarily(long receiverId) {
    this.currentOwnerId = receiverId;
    this.unblockIfBlocked();
}

public void transferPermanently(long receiverId) {
    transferTemporarily(receiverId);
    this.actualOwnerId = receiverId;
}
```

Alternatively, if reading `temporarily` inside a `permanent` method is slightly confusing, have a new method `setCurrentOwnerAndUnblock()` to do that instead...

Comment: *Since the use of realized and cancelled are just opposites of each other, you may want to consider having just a single boolean field.* I can't just do that, because, before the transfer time they are both false, but I think you're right. There may be a tri-state enum `{PENDING, REALIZED, CANCELLED}` there.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca sorry for that wrong assumption, as there wasn't enough context to realize that in the first place... I thought you are just interested to know if the transfer is 'accepted' or not.